# How to type cast fixed size byte arrays in solc 0.5.x?

Tags: solc, solidity-0.5.x, type-casting

In solc 0.4.28 I was able to do:

```
uint foo = 42;
bytes28 bar = bytes28(foo);
```

but in 0.5.9 I'm getting the error:

```
TypeError: Explicit type conversion not allowed from "uint256" to "bytes28".
        bytes28 bar = bytes28(foo);
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out...
You have to cast the uint to the same length so in this case it would be:

```
bytes28 bar = bytes28(uint224(foo));
```

If it were `bytes16` it would be:

```
bytes16 bar = bytes28(uint128(foo));
```

bytes vs bits:
28 / 32 == 224 / 256
16 / 32 == 128 / 256